# can't Record animation with hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm trying to build hololens application with unity.
i get an error about the UnityEditor namespace.
is it possible to compile the unity editor to hololens?
if not, what can i do to record animation with hololens?

Comment: Please, can you add the relevant code and the message error?

Comment: Hi, you'll need to specify what you mean by "record animation with Hololens".  Do you mean using the stuff from the Animator and Animation to create animation keyframes while on the device?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. record on animation clip the movements and the materials for example

Comment: You could use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/holographic-remoting-player to run your code in the Unity Editor, but view it on the hololens (it essentially streams a video feed to your hololens, and streams hololens input/position/etc.. back to your unity editor)

That way should be able to use the Unity Editor features, but manipulate things using the hololens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the UnityEditor namespace is for the editor only, and can't be packaged into any apps.  Any functionality you want from that namespace you'll have to find elsewhere, although if you think there's stuff you need from it, it suggests there are design problems - it shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft's site on how to do Mixed reality capture:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mixed-reality-capture

Comment: Thanks!so i can't record animation with hololens? only a video or a picture of the screen?

Comment: What do you mean by record an animation?  If an animation is playing on the screen and you are recording it then that effectively would be recording the animation.